# Error building OpenCV 2.4.x "Undefined reference to av_opt_set@LIBAVUTIL_51"

Tags: opencv, build, undefined

I have tried building all versions of 2.4, and they all fail when "Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_core" with:

```
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_opt_set@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.54: undefined reference to `av_strcasecmp@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_bprint_finalize@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.54: undefined reference to `av_timecode_make_smpte_tc_string@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.54: undefined reference to `av_timecode_make_string@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_realloc_f@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.54: undefined reference to `av_timecode_get_smpte_from_framenum@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.54: undefined reference to `av_timecode_init@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_samples_set_silence@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_calloc@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.54: undefined reference to `av_opt_get@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.54: undefined reference to `av_strncasecmp@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_samples_fill_arrays@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_get_media_type_string@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.54: undefined reference to `av_dynarray_add@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_bprint_init@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_asprintf@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_sample_fmt_is_planar@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_samples_get_buffer_size@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.54: undefined reference to `av_opt_get_int@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_timecode_make_mpeg_tc_string@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.54: undefined reference to `av_rescale_q_rnd@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_bprintf@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_samples_copy@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_get_default_channel_layout@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_timecode_init_from_string@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_bprint_chars@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.54: undefined reference to `av_des_mac@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_timecode_adjust_ntsc_framenum@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.54: undefined reference to `av_timegm@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54: undefined reference to `av_tempfile@LIBAVUTIL_51'
```

My CMakeLists.txt file is the default, except I changed it to use TBB, disabled the docs, and turned on verbose mode.

Doing ldd /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54 I get:

```
root@omap4-multi:~/opencv/2.4.3/build# ldd /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.54
    libavutil.so.51 => /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so.51 (0xb6132000)
    libx264.so.123 => /usr/local/lib/libx264.so.123 (0xb5fc4000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0xb5e4a000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libvorbis.so.0 (0xb5e14000)
    libtheoraenc.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libtheoraenc.so.1 (0xb5dcc000)
    libtheoradec.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libtheoradec.so.1 (0xb5dac000)
    libopencore-amrwb.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libopencore-amrwb.so.0 (0xb5d93000)
    libopencore-amrnb.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libopencore-amrnb.so.0 (0xb5d67000)
    libmp3lame.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.so.0 (0xb5cdd000)
    libfaac.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libfaac.so.0 (0xb5cc1000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xb5c44000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb5c29000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb5c02000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb5be3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb5ab8000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libogg.so.0 (0xb5aac000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0x42228000)
```

Anyone have any idea as to what may be causing it, or what I can do to fix it? Ive been working on this for quite awhile and am at a loss. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could try turning off the `WITH_FFMPEG` option in CMake and build it that way, unless you need ffmpeg support for whatever you are doing.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem from downgrading ffmpeg from 0.11 to 0.8. Not sure why that was causing issues, but it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it's a problem with ffmpeg, if you upgraded one or more dependencies of ffmpeg. Ffmpeg needs to be recompiled or updated with all its dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well. Even after I re-compile ffmpeg, the problem still remains. Finally, I realise a conflict between ffmpeg installed from source code with the lib installed by `apt-get`, I mean `libavutil-dev`, `libavutil-extra-51`. Simply removing ffmpeg using `apt-get remove ffmpeg` did not solve this problem. My solution is is to remove the conflict lib installed from `apt` as follows:

```
sudo apt-get remove libavutil-dev libavutil-extra-51
```

Hope it's useful to you.